# Could 2D critical quantum system be described by 3D conformal field theory?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, critical-phenomena

It is well known that 1D quantum critial systems are described by 2D cft. Could 2D critical quantum system be described by 3D conformal field theory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, this does not mean that all 3+1 dimensional theories with a CFT on their boundary can be described using a conformal field theory. A large amount of evidence suggests that they cannot in general.